# Why every short exact sequence of finitely generated $\mathbb{C}G$-modules splits?

Tags: exact-sequence

Let $G$ be a finite group and $\mathbb{C}$ be the complex field.
$L,M,N$ are finitely generated $\mathbb{C}G$-modules (Where $\mathbb{C}G$ denotes a group ring).

Show if
 $$0\rightarrow L \rightarrow M \rightarrow N\rightarrow 0$$
is a short exact sequence then it splits.

Comment: This is textbook representation theory - namely Maschke's theorem. The typical proof involves Weyl's unitary trick: put an inner product on $M$, average it over $G$ to make it invariant, then define the orthogonal complement of $L$, which you can verify is also invariant, and so $M$ is a direct sum.